# Disable Login redirect of ASP.net Web Pages

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms, asp.net-webpages

I have Web Site application using Web Forms. I add a Razor Web Page and loading it up using below code:

```
    var webPage = WebPage.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/WebPage.cshtml"); 

    var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    var pageContext = new WebPageContext(httpContext, webPage, new Class1 { Number1 = 100 });

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        webPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(pageContext, writer);
    }

    string output = sb.ToString();
```

Above compiles only if I this webpages:Enabled to "true" on my config. Another problem is the Web site uses Forms authentication, it redirects to /Account/Login instead to a Login.aspx as defined in the config.

I really need to Razor Web Page enabled and use the Login.aspx for form authentication. Anyone can help how to disable the login redirect?

Or anyone can share other code on how to load a Razor web page output from Web Forms?

Comment: Solve my own problem. Just need to add reference or install from Nuget of the ASP.NET Web Pages.

Answer (score 1):

Check the authentication node under system.web section in web.config. 
By default : it is pointing to ~/Account/Login. You may want to change that :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Yeah you need to change it to the value you need to have. Have you done that ?